# Fixed header table inside a scrollable div with equal 'table head column width' and 'content column width'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a big table inside a div with scroll-x and scroll-y. What I want is to just make the table header fixed when scrolling in y-axis.

I can set the table header at the top of the div but it is not respecting overflow-x. and also  **the table head column width needs to be same as the column of the content.**

How can I attain this?

Comment: Post your source code for us to better understand what you want.

Comment: I am sorry its a big code. I need to edit a lot to make it simpler to post it here. I will edit the question now.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a demo [Fixed Header Demo](http://jsbin.com/AjiJIGA/1) .

I explored your problem and got a solution [I believe there is no pure css solution exits.!]. Also, You are most welcome to optimize this.

```
//Script

 <script>

 var maxw = 0;
 $(document).ready( function () {

  $('.Top2').bind('scroll', function(){
     $(".Top1").scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
  });

      var len = $("table.head > tbody").find("> tr:first > td").length;
       for(i=0; i<len;i++) {
           maxval(i);
       maxw = 0 ;
       }     

   });

function maxval(index) {

    $("table").find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
                var $tds = $(this).find('td');
                w = $tds.eq(index).width(); 
                if(w>maxw){
                maxw = w; //Get max width for the column i
                }       
    });
   myf(maxw,index); // Set the css according to 'td'
}

function myf(maxw,index){
 $("table").find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
     var $tds =  $(this).find('td');
     $tds.eq(index).css("padding-right", maxw- ($tds.eq(index).width()));  // patch : Is any other way?
 });
}
   </script>
```

Also check my updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JeekOnline/A79e2/59/).